# How to select values that are out of range?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi there I have a table with the structure below:

```
create table prices(
    id int not null,
    mini float not null,
    maxi float not null,

    primary key (id)
);
```

And I select the ids of the rows which are within an specific range. 
The following fiddle speaks for itself: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5885d/2**

```
set @pmini1 = 82.5;
set @pmaxi1 = 85.5;

select *
from prices
where ((@pmini1 between mini and maxi) or 
(@pmaxi1 between mini and maxi));
```

---

Ok, so know what I' trying to implement this conditions:

- if the range is higher than the highest maxi of the table, then it'd
  select the id of the element with the highest maxi.
- if the range is lower than the lowest mini of the table, then it'd select the id of
  the element with the lowest mini.

Is possible to do that without using more that one query?
Any advice or tip would be appreciated.

If you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to calculate the minimum of mini and the maximum of maxi and then use these for comparison:

```
select *
from prices p cross join
     (select MIN(mini) as minmini, MAX(maxi) as maxmaxi from p) const
where ((@pmini1 between p.mini and p.maxi) or 
       (@pmaxi1 between p.mini and p.maxi) or
       (@pmini1 < const.minmini and p.mini = const.minmini) or
       (@pmaxi1 > const.maxmaxi and p.maxi = const.maxmaxi)
      )
```

In MySQL, you can also phrase this more succinctly as:

```
select *
from prices p cross join
     (select MIN(mini) as minmini, MAX(maxi) as maxmaxi from p) const
where ((greatest(@pmini1, const.minmini) between p.mini and p.maxi) or 
       (least(@pmaxi1, const.maxmaxi) between p.mini and p.maxi)
      )
```

Comment: Your 100% correct in your approach on the cross join, if you want to complete the solution I would change your approach into a union, possibly with a top 1 depending on if OP wants all the elements, or if he wanted just the single lowest and highest.